# RAM usage is increasing in database server with time

Tags: sql-server-2008

RAM usage is increasing in database server with time. When we restart the SQL services it take around 4 GB but after day or two it increases to 11-12 GB and even further.
Application is hosted on separate server. Please suggest what could be the reason.

Comment: Database uses available memory to cache and for other operations.. Can you please elaborate on what specific issue / things you are looking for.. Otherwise, the question seems too general.

Comment: Why is RAM usage even a problem?

Comment: The problem is that Ram is not getting released and its a 16 GB RAM server. Once it reached to 15 GB usage and server got chocked. I need to restart the service as I left with no other option.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will try and use all the RAM it can get hold of to reduce execution times on queries.

As you have had it running for a day or two, with the increased amount of queries ran it will be using as much RAM that it has available to it.

Comment: Is there a way to release the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to find a way to release your RAM, you might be better served trying to determine how much of your RAM your SQL server is allowed to use.

Seeing as how you're using a 16GB server, try leaving 2-3GB for the OS (or more depending on what else is installed on there)

The following commands would set your max server memory (the amount of memory SQL server will keep a hold of) to 12GB:

```
sp_configure 'max server memory', 12288;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx